# Unset session by selecting dropdown menu option

Tags: php, jquery, session

I would like to add an option in my drop down menu that unset or destroys the session `$_SESSION['selected_opt]`.

Practice code:

```
<form class="search-form">
    <select name="thema" class="selectpicker">
        <option value="t1" class="special">Select something</option>
            <optgroup label="Select...">
                <option value="s1" data-icon="glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet" class="special">Selection 1</option>
                <option value="s1" data-icon="glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet" class="special">Selection 2</option>
                <option value="s1" data-icon="glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet" class="special">Selection 3</option>
                <option value="s4" data-icon="glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet" class="special">Selection 1</option>
            </optgroup>
    </select>
</form>
```

I've seen some code's like this around:

```
<option value="black" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['kategorie']) == "black") { echo ' selected';} ?>>Black and white</option>
```

So I've put something like that in the code:

```
<option value="t1" <?php if($_SESSION['selected_opt']) { unset($_SESSION['selected_opt']);} ?> class="class_opt">Select something</option>
```

But of course this didn't work. Is this at all possible or should I use something like jQuery? I could find a suitable answer anywhere... I hope someone can help...

Comment: Just call a `$.get` request to a url that contains `unset($_SESSION['selected_opt'])`. Session is handle by server so jquery can not destroy user's session.

Comment: @vietnguyen09 Do you perhaps have some sort of code snippet or example for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
<select name="thema" class="selectpicker" change='selectChanged(this);'>
```

and create the function:

```
<script>
function selectChanged(obj){
    if($(obj).val() == "LogOut"){
         //redirect to your session clearing / log out page
         window.location.href = 'http://example.com/LogOut.php''
    };
});
</script>
```

and your option will be:

```
<option value="LogOut">Log Out</option>
```